# Create shortcut to system apk that doesn't have a shortcut

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

So I have a MTK Android Phone, the gps of which sucks. Only App that can get a fix is ygps.apk in engineering mode. I have to keep it running background so other gps apps can get fix. Every time I want to launch this app I need to go to engineering mode, although my phone is rooted and I know where the YGPS.apk is.

Can I create a shortcut for this app so i can launch it with one click?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create link to app that does not appear in the apps menu?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62538/how-to-create-link-to-app-that-does-not-appear-in-the-apps-menu)

Answer (score 2):

Several launchers can do that, e.g. *Apex* and *Nova*. You pretend to create a shortcut, select "Activities", browse for the app you normally use to enter engineering mode, and see what activities it provides. Should have one for that YGPS if you normally launch it from there.

There are other tools available specifically creating similar shortcuts (if you don't want to use one of those browsers), e.g. [Activity Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/activity-launcher/de.szalkowski.activitylauncher) should be worth a closer look then.

In either case, you get a complete list of all available apps – regardless of whether they are shown in your app drawer or are hidden from it. So even if that YGPS is a separate app, it should show up here with its activities. If its an activity of some other app, it should show up there.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same experience with YGPS.

QuickShortcut Maker is an app that allows you to create a shortcut to an application from the list of activities which are installed on your phone.

This works with YGPS and YGPS works when launched this way.

Answer (score 0):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) could do something for you, like start the ygps app [before](http://tasker.wikidot.com/prelaunch) the 'real' one starts.

Comment: Tasker is a app with lots of functions. Please explain here how to achieve the goal.